# Prove the following when $\cos(\beta-\gamma)+\cos(\gamma-\alpha)+\cos(\alpha-\beta)=-\frac{3}{2}$:

Tags: trigonometry

> Given,
>   $$\cos(\beta-\gamma)+\cos(\gamma-\alpha)+\cos(\alpha-\beta)=-\frac{3}{2}$$
>   Prove that:
>
> 1. $\cos\alpha+\cos\beta+\cos\gamma=0$
> 2. $\sin\alpha+\sin\beta+\sin\gamma=0$

It would be especially helpful if anyone would point out a way to do these quickly, in competitive examinations, such as in True or False questions.

Comment: Hint: Imagine you have 3 unit vectors $x_1 = (\cos\alpha,\sin\alpha), x_2 = (\cos\beta,\sin\beta), x_3 = (\cos\gamma,\sin\gamma)$. What is $x_1 \cdot x_2$, $x_2\cdot x_3$, $x_3 \cdot x_1$ and $|x_1 + x_2 + x_3|^2$ ?

Comment: @achillehui Sorry, I don't know about vectors yet.

Comment: Okay, what do you get if you expand $(\cos\alpha + \cos\beta + \cos\gamma)^2 + (\sin\alpha+\sin\beta + \sin\gamma)^2$? Remember you can group some of terms together using identities like $\cos(\alpha - \beta) = \cos\alpha\cos\beta + \sin\alpha\sin\beta$.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1397066/clarification-regarding-a-question/1397721

Answer (score 1):

You have $$\cos(\beta-\gamma)+\cos(\gamma-\alpha)+\cos(\alpha-\beta)=-\frac{3}{2}$$
From this we have $$-2(\cos\alpha \cos\beta+\cos\beta\cos\gamma+\cos\gamma\cos\alpha)+2(\sin\alpha \sin\beta+\sin\beta\sin\gamma+\sin\gamma\sin\alpha)=3\left(\sum_{cyclic} \cos^2 \alpha+\sum_{cyclic} \sin^2 \alpha\right)\\\implies\left(\sum_{cyclic}\cos\alpha\right)^2+\left(\sum_{cyclic}\sin\alpha\right)^2=0.$$

So, $$\begin{align}
\sum_{cyclic}\cos\alpha&=0,\\
\text{and}\sum_{cyclic}\sin\alpha&=0
\end{align}$$