# Given that $\cos A + \cos B + \cos C = 0$ and $\sin A + \sin B + \sin C = 0$.

Tags: trigonometry

If  $\cos A + \cos B + \cos C = 0$ and $\sin A + \sin B + \sin C = 0$.

The value of $ \sin^3A+\sin^3B+\sin^3C$

What I can see here is that as $\sin A + \sin B + \sin C = 0$ hence $ \sin^3A+\sin^3B+\sin^3C=3\sin A \sin B\sin C$  but I am not able to achieve a constant value. Please give some hint.

Comment: @egreg No they aren't.

Comment: Sorry for the noise, they obviously aren't!

Comment: @Ananya, Find the necessary & the sufficient condition : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1397066/clarification-regarding-a-question

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Thank you. That was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If the centroid of a triangle coincides with it circumcenter, the triangle is equilateral.

**Answer:**  $\sin^3(A)+\sin^3(B)+\sin^3(C)=3\sin^3(A)-\frac{9}{4}\sin(A)=-\frac{3}{4}\sin(3A)$.

Comment: So how does this help here?

Comment: You have from this hint that we may assume $B=A+\frac{2\pi}{3}$ and $C=A-\frac{2\pi}{3}$.  Hence, the require sum is $3\sin^3(A)-\frac{9}{4}\sin(A)=-\frac{3}{4}\sin(3A)$.