# Prove that $\tan 3a = \tan 3b = \tan 3c$ if $\sin a + \sin b + \sin c = 0$ and $\cos a + \cos b + \cos c = 0$

Tags: trigonometry

Let $a, b$ and $c$ be three angles such that:
$$\sin a + \sin b + \sin c = 0$$
$$\cos a + \cos b + \cos c = 0$$

Prove that $\tan 3a = \tan 3b = \tan 3c$.

I haven't done anything meaningful yet on this problem because I have no idea how I should start.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You might want to look at: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1970511/if-sin-a-sin-b-sin-c-cos-a-cos-b-cos-c-0-prove-that?rq=1

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1397066/clarification-regarding-a-question

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**By geometry**:

$(\cos a,\sin a),(\cos b,\sin b),(\cos c,\sin c)$ are three unit vectors which sum to zero.

Then they must be the vertices of an equilateral triangle inscribed in the trigonometric circle, at angles $$k\frac{2\pi}3+\phi$$ for $k=0,1,2$.

Obviously,

$$\tan\left(3\left(k\frac{2\pi}3+\phi\right)\right)=\tan3\phi$$ for all $k$.

---

From this finding, we can derive a more analytical solution.

Combining the two initial equations, we must have

$$(\sin a+\sin b)^2+(\cos a+\cos b)^2=(-\sin c)^2+(-\cos c)^2=1$$ or after simplification $$2\sin a\sin b+2\cos a\cos b=2\cos(a-b)=-1$$
giving
$$a-b=\pm\frac{2\pi}3.$$

By symmetry, this holds for $b-c$ and $c-a$ and leads us to

$$b=a\pm\frac{2\pi}3,c=a\mp\frac{2\pi}3,$$
then
$$3b=3a\pm2\pi,3c=3a\mp2\pi.$$

Comment: This is very elegant. +1

Comment: Yes the geometric approach is always enlightening.

Answer (score 0):

We have

$sin(a)=-sin(b)-sin(c)$

and

$cos(a)=-cos(b)-cos(c)$

thus

$1=2+2sin(b)sin(c)+2cos(b)cos(c)$

$\implies$

$cos(b-c)=-\frac 12=cos(a-b)=cos(a-c)$

$\implies$

$b-c=\pm\frac{2\pi}{3}+2k_1\pi$

and

$a-b=\pm\frac{2\pi}{3}+2k_2\pi$

$\implies$

$\tan(3a)=\tan(3b)=\tan(3c)$.

Comment: What does this add to my answer ?

Comment: You wrote it an hour later and the $2k\pi$ does not matter as you are taking the tangent.