# How do I do it using complex numbers?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

> If $\;\cos\alpha+\cos\beta+\cos\gamma= \sin\alpha+\sin\beta+\sin\gamma=0$, then show that
> $\cos^2\!\alpha+\cos^2\!\beta+\cos^2\!\gamma=\sin^2\!\alpha+\sin^2\!\beta+\sin^2\!\gamma=\!3/2$

I have done this problem with just trigonometric identities, but I want to know how can I get it with complex numbers.

I have tried and gotten the following results,

$\mathrm{CiS}(\alpha)+\mathrm{CiS}(\beta)+\mathrm{CiS}(\gamma)=0$

$\mathrm{CiS}^2(\alpha) + \mathrm{CiS}^2(\beta) + \mathrm{CiS}^2(\gamma) = 0$

I have seen very similar questions with the same given condition and tried methods from there but I couldn't solve it all the way. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: ${CiS}^2(\alpha) = CiS(2 \alpha)$, Consider the real part of your second equation and apply the double angle formula for cosine: $\cos (2 \alpha) = 2 \cos^2 (\alpha) - 1 = 1 - 2 \sin^2 (\alpha)$.

Comment: What is $\mathrm{CiS}(\alpha)$ ? Is it $\,\cos\alpha+i\sin\alpha$ ?

Comment: That's right, it's just a shorthand notation.

Comment: @Angelo See [cis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cis_(mathematics))

Comment: @0x13 There are no other conditions on $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$? They don't, say, add up to $\pi$ (i.e. form a triangle)?

Comment: Thanks! that did it, I had previously applied De Moivre's formula. but hadn't done the double angle part. @Zerox

Comment: @user170231 No such conditions were given.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2184255/prove-that-z-12-z-22-z-32-0 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1397066/clarification-regarding-a-question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$CiS(\alpha)=x, CiS(\beta)=y, CiS(\gamma)=z$$

$$x+y+z = (\cos(\alpha)+\cos(\beta)+\cos(\gamma))+i(\sin(\alpha)+\sin(\beta)+\sin(\gamma)=0+i(0))=0$$

$$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z} = (\cos(\alpha)+\cos(\beta)+\cos(\gamma))-i(\sin(\alpha)+\sin(\beta)+\sin(\gamma)) = 0$$
$$xy+yz+zx=0$$

Therefore, $x^2+y^2+z^2 = 0$

$$CiS(\alpha)^2+CiS(\beta)^2+CiS(\gamma)^2 = 0$$
$$(\cos(2\alpha)+i\sin(2\alpha))+(\cos(2\beta)+i\sin(2\beta))+(\cos(2\gamma)+i\sin(2\gamma))=0$$
$$1-2\sin^2(\alpha)+i\sin(2\alpha)+1-2\sin^2(\beta)+i\sin(2\beta)+1-2\sin^2(\gamma)+i\sin(2\gamma)=0$$
$$3-2(\sin^2(\alpha)+\sin^2(\beta)+\sin^2(\gamma))+i(\sin(2\alpha)+\sin(2\beta)+\sin(2\gamma))=0+i(0)$$

Comparing the real part of this equation,
$$\sin^2(\alpha)+\sin^2(\beta)+\sin^2(\gamma) = \frac{3}{2}$$

It is now apparent that,
$$\cos^2(\alpha)+\cos^2(\beta)+\cos^2(\gamma) = \frac{3}{2}$$

Comment: Yes, there were some typos, I have edited the answer accordingly. @Angelo