# Let $z_1,z_2,z_3 \in \mathbb{C}$ with $z_i=1$ for $i=1,2,3$ and $z_1+z_2+z_3$. Show that $z_i$ are vertices for a equilateral triangle.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, systems-of-equations

Let $z_1,z_2,z_3 \in \mathbb{C}$ with $z_i=1$ for $i=1,2,3$ and $z_{1}+z_{2}+z_3=0$. Show that $z_i$ are vertices for a equilateral triangle.

Tip: Think about the case $z_3=1$. What then follows the general case?

**My attempt:**

Since $z_3=1=1+0i$, it must be $z_1+z_2=-1$ with $z_1:=a_1+ib_1$ and $z_2:=a_2+ib_2$. Adding these equations leads to $(a_1+a_2)+i(b_1+b_2)=-1+0i$.

So $a_1+a_2=-1$ and $b_1+b_2=0$. Now I am stuck with my argumentation, there are just too many variables...

Any Ideas?

Comment: You mean $|z_i|=1$ and $z_1+z_2+z_3=0$.

Comment: Yeah, sorry...!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1397066/clarification-regarding-a-question

Comment: Hello bhattacharjee, how does that help me?

Comment: You already asked this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3231962/show-that-z-1-z-2-z-3-are-vertices-of-an-isoceles-triangle-complex-plane

Comment: Sadly, I can't edit my question and I already have an attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is
$$
z_1=1\\
z_2=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cdot i\\
z_3=-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cdot i
$$
[image]

If $\vec{z}_1=(x,y)$, $\vec{z}_2=(z,w)$ and $\vec{z}_3=(u,v)$ then by figure
\begin{align}
(z-u)^2+(w-v)^2=&(z-x)^2+(w-y)^2\\
(z-x)^2+(w-y)^2=&(u-x)^2+(v-y)^2\\
(z-u)^2+(w-v)^2=&(u-x)^2+(v-y)^2\\
\end{align}
By $\|z_i\|=1$, $i=1,2,3$, we have
\begin{align}
z^2+w^2=&1\\
u^2+v^2=&1\\
x^2+y^2=&1\\
\end{align}

By $z_1+z_2+z_3=0$ we have
\begin{align}
u+x+z=&0\\
v+y+w=&0\\
\end{align}
Now use those $ 8 $ equations to get the answer that was given.

Comment: Sorry, It must be $|z_i|=1$

Comment: And how? How did you find $a,b$?

Comment: I got it. :-) Thanks

Comment: Woah, thanks for your effort. But I solved it way easier. Look at my attempt. The missing two equations necessary to solve for all variables are $a_1+a_2=-1$, $b_1+b_2=0$, $a_1^2+b_1^2=1$ and $a_2^2+b_2^2=1$.

Comment: Often easier just means "with less detail." For example, why can we take $z_3 = 1$ without loss of generality? It's intuitively clear and, depending on context, might not require justification, but if you had to justify it, could you? Could you do it in fewer steps than MathOverview's solution takes?

Comment: Probably not, sorry. :-(

Answer (score 0):

As $|z_j|=1$ then $\overline z_j=z_j^{-1}$. Then as $\overline{z_1}+\overline{z_2}+\overline{z_3}=0$,
$$z_2z_3+z_3z_1+z_1z_2=z_1z_2z_3(z_1^{-1}+z_2^{-1}+z_3^{-1})=0$$
and then the $z_j$ are the roots of
$$w^3-z_1z_2z_3=0.$$
As the three cube roots of a complex number, they form the vertices
of an equilateral triangle centred at the origin.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is my attempt wrong?