# TIFR 2011 complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

Three distinct points $x, y, z$ lie on a unit circle of the complex plane and satisfy $x+y+z=0$. Then $x, y, z$ form the vertices of.

1. An isosceles but not equilateral triangle.
2. An equilateral triangle.
3. A triangle of any shape.
4. A triangle whose shape can't be determined.
5. None of the above.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: **please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem.** These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @MartinR I'm new in this topic, I'm unable to solve, please explain.

Comment: What does $x + y + z = 0$ mean? That if you treat them as vectors, their sum is the zero vector?

Comment: 2) Equilateral triangle, example are cube root of unity

Comment: @AjayMishra Can you write the answer in a detailed way

Comment: I just want to say that the answer is 2) An equilateral triangle using symmetry

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1397066/clarification-regarding-a-question

Answer (score 1):

The points $0, x, y, x+y$ form a parallelogram but $x+y=-z$ which implies $|x+y|=|z|=|x|=|y|$. This means that both $0, x, x+y$ and $0, y, x+y$ form congruent equilateral triangles. Similarly, $x, -z, y, -x, z, -y$ form the vertices of a regular hexagon and hence $x, y, z$ form an equilateral triangle.

Another solution: Suppose $a, b, c$ are three points. Assume that thetriangle ($\triangle abc$) has centroid $d$ which is also the center of the circumcircle ($\bigcirc abc$). By using a complex linear transformation
 ($\, z \mapsto (z-d)/(c-d)\,$) we can assume (without loss of generality) that 
$$d=0,\quad c=1,\quad a+b=-1, |a|=|b|=1.$$ Now also $\,\bar{a}+\bar{b}=-1\,$ and this implies the diagonals of quadrilateral $\,a\bar{b}b\bar{a}\,$ bisect each other and hence is a parallelogram. This now implies that $\,a=\bar{b}\,$ and they are primitive curbe roots of unity. Hence $\triangle abc$ is equilateral.

Comment: +1 Another way along these lines: $0,x,y,x+y$ clearly forms a rhombus with side lengths $1$.  Then $x,z,x+y$ is clearly a right triangle with hypotenuse 2 and short side 1, so it is a 30-60-90.  The same is true for $y,z, x+y$. So the angle $\angle xzy$ is 60. By symmetry, so are the remaining angles in the triangle formed by $xyz$

Comment: @rschwieb I don't see the reason why $x,z,x+y$ is a right triangle. It is not clear to me. What is the reason for it?

Comment: that's a classic theorem of geometry: a triangle inscribed in a circle such that the hypotenuse is the diameter is a right triangle.

Comment: @rschwieb You are right, of course.

Comment: Actually, since the focus of this question is complex numbers, I was really hoping to find an algebraic solution... but as usual it seems much easier to reason geometrically.

Answer (score 0):

Let's prove the answer is 2).

Write $x=e^{ia}$ etc. so $e^{ia}+e^{ib}+e^{ic}=0$ and $e^{i(b-a)}+e^{i(c-a)}=-1$. Equating imaginary parts, $\sin(b-a)=\sin(a-c)$; equating real ones, $\cos(b-a)+\cos(a-c)=-1$. The cosines are equal, rather than equal and opposite, and so each is $-\frac12$, whence $\sin(b-a)=\pm\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}=\pm\sin\frac{2\pi}{3}$. Note in particular that $\cos(b-a)=-\frac12\implies b-a\ne\pm\frac{\pi}{3}$.

The angles between $x,\,y,\,z$ are $\frac{2\pi}{3}$ each, while the circumradii at the vertices split $\triangle xyz$ into isosceles triangles of base angles $\frac12\left(\pi-\frac{2\pi}{3}\right)=\frac{\pi}{6}$. Thus each internal angle of $\triangle xyz$ is $\frac{\pi}{3}$, as expected.