# Show that complex numbers satisfying $z_1 + z_2 + z_3 = z_1^2 + z_2^2 + z_3^2 = 0$ have equal module $|z_1|=|z_2|=|z_3|$

Tags: complex-numbers

I have 3 complex number $z_1,\> z_2, \>z_3$ from C and i know that:
$$z_1 + z_2 + z_3 = 0 , \>\>\>\>\> z_1^2 + z_2^2 + z_3^2 = 0$$
I have to show that 
$$|z_1|=|z_2|=|z_3|$$

Comment: Try writing them in the froms $z_1=a_1+ib_2$ .... substitute in the equations that you have, and look at the real part alone and the imaginary part alone (they both equal $0$). Also don't forget to show what you tried please.

Comment: @FareedAbiFarraj i've tried that and from first equation i've got that the sum of real and imaginary components are 0 and from the second one i have x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 - y_1^2 - y_2^2 - y_3^2 + 2 * i * (x_1 * y_1 + x_2 * y_2 + x_3 * y_3) = 0. I don't see how this should help me..

Comment: Show that $z_i$ are the roots of $z^3 - a = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the given,

$$ z_1z_2 + z_2z_3 +z_3z_1  =\frac12 \left[(z_1 + z_2 + z_3)^2 - (z_1^2 + z_2^2 + z_3^2) \right]= 0 $$

Substitute lhs with $z_3=-(z_1 + z_2)$,

$$z_1z_2 - (z_1 +z_2)^2 = 0 \implies z_1^2 + z_1z_2 + z_2^2 =0$$

which yields $ {z_1} = \frac12(-1\pm\sqrt3 i){z_2}=e^{i \pi \pm i\frac\pi3}{z_2}\implies \left|{z_1}\right| = |{z_2}|$ and likewise  $|{z_1}|= |{z_3}|$. Thus,

$$|z_1|=|z_2|=|z_3|$$

Comment: should'n be there e^i*(pi+-pi/3). And why do they have equal module?

Comment: @Nicoara - you’re right; should be 2nd and 3rd quadrants. Thanks for spotting it and corrected

Comment: but can you explain a little why do they have equal module?

Comment: @Nicoara Note $\frac{z_1}{z_2} = e^{i a}$. Take module $\left|\frac{z_1}{z_2}\right|^2= e^{i a}e^{-i a}=1$

Answer (score 0):

In

[If $z_1^2+z_2^2+z_3^2=z_1z_2+z_2z_3+z_3z_1$ , PT $z_1,z_2,z_3$ represent the vertices of an equilateral triangle.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3433576/if-z-12z-22z-32-z-1z-2z-2z-3z-3z-1-pt-z-1-z-2-z-3-represent-the-ver/3433581#3433581)

put $a,b,c$ to $z_1,z_2,z_3$ respectively

See also

[Clarification regarding a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1397066/clarification-regarding-a-question)